# How to create a <div> grid using JSTL <c:forEach>?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to create a grid using JSTL `<c:forEach>`.

```html
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" step="1" begin="0">
    <div id="col1">
        <a href="#">${user.userName}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <a href="#">${user.userName}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
        <a href="#">${user.userName}</a>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

The output is:

```
user1   user1   user1
user2   user2   user2
user3   user3   user3
and so on...
```

But I want it to display like:

```
user1   user2   user3
user4   user5   user6
user7   user8   user9
and so on...
```

My CSS is:

```css
#col1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 0px;  
}

#col2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#col3 {
    margin-left: 200px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

How can I achieve this without using a table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a status variable, please try:

```
<c:forEach var="user" varStatus="status" items="${userList}" step="1" begin="0">
  <div id="col${status.index % 3 + 1}">
    <a href="#">${user.userName}</a>
  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I also recommend to replace `id=colX"` by `class="colX"` and declare CSS as `.col1`, `.col2` and `.col3`, because IDs are supposed to be **unique** throughout the HTML document. If you use IDs this way, you end up in invalid HTML.

Comment: Thanks ControlPower. Great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<c:set var="count" value="1"/>
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" step="1" begin="0">
 <c:if test="${count==4}">
   <c:set var="count" value="1"/>
 </c:if>
 <div id="col${count}">
    <a href="#">${user.userName}</a>
 </div>
 <c:set var="count" value="${count+1}"/>
</c:forEach>
```