# Display a list of items in a grid in JSF 1.1

Tags: list, jsf, arraylist, grid, jsf-1.2

I need to display a list of items in a grid using JSF 1.1 and Tomahawak.

I tried this

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:dataTable value="#{globalTVChannelsBean.filteredChannels}" var="channel">
        <h:column><h:outputText value="#{channel.channelName}" /></h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:panelGrid>
```

and this

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <c:forEach items="#{globalTVChannelsBean.filteredChannels}" var="channel"
        <h:outputText value="#{channel.channelName}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

but they both are not working. Could you see the problem, or suggest the correct way of doing it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The values are displayed in one column, whereas, I want them to be displayed in four columns as in a grid.

Comment: That's because you have specified one column!

Comment: If I write two columns than it will duplicate the first column. However, I don't want a value to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look closer on how dataTable component works.

[DataTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/dataTable.html) generates an HTML table for you. In your case, you need to use [ui:repeat](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) which loops over an array without creating HTML table tags.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <ui:repeat value="#{globalTVChannelsBean.filteredChannels}" var="channel">
        <h:outputText value="#{channel.channelName}" />
    </ui:repeat>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: ui:repeat is not available to me in the project.

Comment: Is it possible to include Facelets in your project? If you can't then try JSTL c:foreach instead

Comment: I suggest you to include Facelets in your project

Comment: I cannot use Facelets, the project is configured with JSF 1.1.

Comment: I believe  Facelets 1.1.8 can be used with JSF 1.1

Answer (score 0):

I could not do it with JSF, however, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7670821/1875434) helped in doing it with JSTL c:forEach.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include this in order to use `c:forEach`

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Comment: It's helpful to mention why you down voted my answer!